# Exp error in Unix

Tags: readline

Simply put, I get a ` exp error when trying to start a different shell from my putty session.
This is my .bashrc file

```
export QHOME=/opt/q
export PATH=$PATH:$QHOME
alias q='rlwrap -c q'
```

The paths are correct, I can't find any information on the error.

```
[myname@dev-unixtrain ~]$ q
xxx+ 2.7 2011.08.16 Copyright (C) xxxx-xxxx Name Systems
l64/ 1()core 992MB myname dev-unixtrain.company.com 10.29.4.56  2014.03.16     company.com INTERNAL #45486
'exp
```

So it loads up and automatically goes back to the unix shell.

Any ideas on what the cause might be??

TIA

Comment: I don't see any error. Since the purpose of `rlwrap` is to provide `readline`-editing for the wrapped program, and you don't say what `q` is, it's possible that `rlwrap` is just waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

This is a licence error. You're trying to use q with an expired licence.